# NgTemplate Bootstrap not take my CSS class

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I created a css modification to change the modal width to 50% against 100% of the view. But the class modal-content is duplicated against modificated.

[image]

[image]

> CSS

```
  .modal-content{
    width: 50%;
  }
```

> HTML

```
<ng-template #content>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> A
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> B
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue in my development and i found the solution with help of `windowClass` in ng-bootstrap

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(UserPasswordComponent, {
  windowClass: 'custom-modal-width' // add a custom class here where you open the modal
});
```

In your `style.css` control the width

```
.custom-modal-width .modal-content {
    width: 50%;
}
```

make sure to remove your `model-content` class in your template

Comment: Perfect! It works for me! But it is possible to set this class in the component.css against style.css?

Comment: no, because the modal created in body and it is not related to our component